# How to use regex to get numeric id from URL?

Tags: c#, regex

Given the links `abc.com/details.php?id=776282&hit=1` and `xyz.com/details.php?id=68990`, how can I use one regex to get id 776282 and 68990 from them, respectively?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I rephrased your question body so it flows more smoothly and is clearer, and added code formatting to make it plainer what the sample data is. I also [removed a tag from the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) and rephrased it a bit to be less redundant and more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Regex` will be `(\d+)`. It retreives the `id` value correctly without including any `spaces`, if `&hit=1` is present *or* not present in the `url`

[***Example Demo***](https://regex101.com/r/dL0pP1/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
[^?]+(?:\?id=([^&]+).*)?
```

[DEMO HERE](https://regex101.com/r/bE7bG5/1)